# How can I select text from element by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

For example we have the next code (it could be any tag with nested tags and text):

```
<td id='test'>
Hello
<a href='foo.html'>JS</a>
<noindex>Map</noindex>
Take me
<div>nice</div>
Skip me
</tr>
```

How can I retrieve '**Take me**' by jQuery selectors ? 
NOTE: `$('#test').text()` will return all texts: Hello JS ...

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Comment: You can't, easily, with the HTML as specified. The best thing to do would be to wrap "Take me" in tags (span, for example), and select that.
Failing that, you could get ALL the text, as you said, then extract the text between the noindex and div tags. That's really not a good idea though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `contents()` to get all the child nodes, then filter through looking for text nodes which match your criteria of containing `"Hello"`.

```
$('#test').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.data) == 'Take me';
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4GH9/).

Comment: it just doesn't make much sense to explicitly filter for a text which you already know. OP needs to make clear a "selector criteria".

Comment: @jAndy It doesn't seem that odd to me. Maybe the OP wants to change that text node.

Comment: no downvoting here. Well you might be right, however should be way more elegant for the OP to put those TextNodes into queryable elements.

Comment: @jAndy Agreed, but sometimes the HTML is not easily modified (outputted from an archaic CMS like my current predicament).